# How do I get all of the project templates in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2017 and the only project template that I have available in C# is `Windows Classic Desktop`.
I must have messed the installation somehow.
How can I get the other project templates, such as .NET Core, Web, etc?
The one I really need is the console project template.

Comment: you could rerun the setup and select the items you want to install, or i believe you could select online templates when making a new project to select/use/install non downloaded templates

Comment: What does the installer show is there? Run the "Visual Studio Installer", see what's checked, and check the options that aren't present.

Comment: Boy I feel stupid...I noticed the link to install templates below the `Online` option and am currently installing the templates that I need.  Thanks!